# Python gc.collect taking almost all of the time in django api call

Tags: python, django, pandas, optimization, garbage-collection

I have an api which processes some data using pandas and then sends back the result however on closer inspection I saw that the Api was taking around 1.5mins. 
I am using import_module to load a module which then has this gc.collect problem.

[image: Code to lode module dynamically]

[image: cprofile output]

Comment: Isn't there circular call in line 121 ? Think you can just call already loaded transformer, not eval self recursion.

Comment: That's not a circular call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out the solution:

Seems like pandas uses forced garbage collection internally in the code which was causing too many gc.collect calls.

So I searched up to disable this and found this issue

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11045

To solve this add the following line to disable this behavior

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
```